# SQL query where one item is always placed last

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query that will display the content of the table by its ID which can be sorted, but I have this one data that I always want to be displayed at the last part, due to some circumstances I cannot simply change its sort ID to that of the last number.

A sample table would be:

```
sort_id | data |
0       | dog  |
1       | cat  |
2       | bear |
3       | wolf |
```

I want this to display as follow: dog,cat,wolf,bear where bear is the constant value that should always be displayed last.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Order by a case statement will work

```
Select *
FROM 
  table1 
ORDER BY
  case when data = 'bear' then 1 else 0 End,
  sort_id
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ab94/2)

Comment: would you mind explaining this to me? this is my first encounter of case in sql. thank you

Comment: @magicianIam here's the reference for case [13.6.5.1. CASE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html)

Answer (score 3):

`SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY data='bear',sort_id`

Comment: +1 nice. of course this only works on MySQL and the case works on everything.

Comment: what would this do exactly?

Comment: @magicianIam: `data='bear'` returns false (0) if `data` is not equal "bear" or true(1) otherwise.  0<1, so rows where data <> 'bear' will always show up before those where data = 'bear'. And yes , as Condrad Frix mentioned it's for mysql; `case` is more generic way (as Russ Cam proposes), but still not absolutely generic (as far as I remember Access doesn't support it)

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following

```
SELECT data
FROM table
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN data = 'bear' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
sort_id
```

We need to introduce the notion of sorting on whether the data is `"bear"` or not before we sort on the `sort_id`.